# How to enumerate paths for all NTFS hard links pointing to a file?

Tags: ntfs, hardlink

I can use `GetFileInformationByHandle` to determine the number of hard links associated with a file. How can I enumerate the paths which make up those links?

For example, if `C:\TEMP_1.BIN` and `C:\TEMP_2.BIN` are hard links to the same content, and I determine from `GetFileInformationByHandle` that `C:\TEMP_1.BIN` has `nNumberOfLinks=2`, how can I discover the path for the other link? (e.g. `C:\TEMP_2.BIN`)

`GetFileInformationByHandle`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [FindFirstFileNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364421%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which tells you all of the names a file has.